# Asp.Net MVC3 RC Razor views : syntax for embedding code inside <javascript> block

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Having trouble embedding c# code inside a javascript block with **MVC3 RC1** razor view. What syntax should I use to make this working? I get warnings eg. Expected constant on the isOk variable among other. (Without text tag, the following code is not recognized as javascript)

```
@{bool isOk = true;}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmp1 = "";
    @if (isOk)
    { 
        <text>
            var tmp=""; // this should be interpreted as javascript
        </text>       
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need the `<text>` tag to indicate that the contents is not evaluated on the server. For example:

```
@{
    var isOK = true;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmp1 = "";
    @if (isOK)
    { 
        <text>
            var tmp = "foo";
        </text>       
    }
</script>
```

will output in the resulting page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmp1 = "";
    var tmp = "foo";
</script>
```

As far as the `Expected Constant` warning is concerned, well, Razor Intellisense is still in beta so it's far from perfect. It's just a warning you can safely ignore. The important thing is what is that the application works and emits valid HTML. Hope this is something that will be fixed in the final product. From personal experience the only warnings I trust are the one emitted by the C# compiler. When I am working in a view I safely ignore all the crappy warnings that Visual Studio emits because I know that it is wrong.

Comment: You're right, in this case the parsers warnings should be ignored. The output is what it should be... thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, the warnings are still here in MVC 3 (final release).

Answer (score 9):

An alternative (more terse and easier to read IMO) is to escape back out to text as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var tmp1 = ""; 
    @if (isOK) 
    {  
        @:var tmp = "foo";
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: True in this case but in a multiline block <text></text> would probably look much neater